# Restore Ubuntu boot manager option while booting

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu

Kubuntu user here.

I am a new Kubuntu user and I was trying to get Windows / Kubuntu and Manjaro on the same machine, however since Manjaro was little bit too much for me I have decided to stay on the Kubuntu / WIN10 combination only. I have managed to delete the partition with Manjaro using KDE partition manager and I have also removed the Manjaro option from the menu in Grub customizer app. However I still need to change something in the boot settings because when I turn on my PC it says that the computer is trying to boot from irrelevant partition and then I only see the grub command line.

Sorry for the poor problem description - I am super new to Linux but I would like to fix it without reinstallation and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QQdYb4Ui

Comment: You have UEFI system & UEFI installs. Do not boot in BIOS mode as that will either boot old BIOS boot loaders & just give error or booting live installer make BIOS repairs when you want UEFI repairs. Reboot in UEFI boot mode & rerun report so all UEFI info is shown. You also have a partitioning overlap error on sdb.  last partition overlaps backup partition table
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1956173
Check start & end, delete and recreate without overlap. Backup vital just in case.

Comment: I have done a clean install but I have figured the UEFI stuff myself before the reinstallation - I have searched in BIOS, found Manjaro EFI files and restored the boot order so I have managed to boot, thank you very much for the help. As for the partition the issue is solved as well. Thanks again!